# How to start sound using picture in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm currently stuck on a problem

I have a picture where i want it to animate as well as start a sound clip. So far, the picture gets animated, but the music won't start.

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").click(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '150px',
                width: '150px'
            });

            function play_single_sound() {
                document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
            };
        });
    });
});
```

This is my index.html where info about my audio ID is:

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="tailtoddle_lo.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your jQuery is set up correctly, you likely want the following

1. remove the nested document.ready
2. actually call the function inside the click

Like this

```
$(function(){
  // tilknyt klik-funktion til alle IMG tags
  $("img").click(function(){
    $('#audiotag1').play();
    $(this).animate({
      height: '150px',
      width: '150px'
    });
  });
});
```

or this

```
function play_single_sound() {
  document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
}

$(function(){
  // tilknyt klik-funktion til alle IMG tags
  $("img").click(function(){
    play_single_sound();
    $(this).animate({
      height: '150px',
      width: '150px'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Damn, i did it with both and didn't know you could only pick one :( Both helped alot

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function `play_single_sound` in `img` click handler as of now you are only defining the function. Also you only need to use one `document-ready` handler.

```
play_single_sound();
```

*Complete Code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '150px',
            width: '150px'
        });
        //Call the function here
        play_single_sound();
    });

    //Define it outside the click handler
    function play_single_sound() {
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
    }
});
```